# Remove a word from a string bash

Tags: bash

I have the string

```
file="this-is-a-{test}file"
```

I want to remove `{test}` from this string.
I used

```
echo $file | sed 's/[{][^}]*//'
```

but this returned me

```
this-is-a-}file
```

How can I remove `}` too?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `sed` with correct regex:

```
s="this-is-a-{test}file"
sed 's/{[^}]*}//' <<< "$s"
this-is-a-file
```

Or this awk:

```
awk -F '{[^}]*}' '{print $1 $2}' <<< "$s"
this-is-a-file
```

Comment: @CiprianVintea The preferred way of saying 'thanks' is by accepting the most helpful answer (click on the green checkmark) to any question you ask (which also increases a bit your reputation too), and by up-voting helpful answers (if you have 15+ reputation).  Please read the [tour], and good luck with the answers.

Answer (score 17):

Also try this bash only oneliner as an alternative:

```
s="this-is-a-{test}file"
echo ${s/\{test\}/}
```